# VB.NET: starting lots of threads takes a long time?

Tags: .net, multithreading, performance, threadpool

I'm trying to write a multithreading application.

Consider the following code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sw As New Stopwatch
    Dim sw2 As New Stopwatch

    sw.Start()

    For x As Integer = 0 To 150
        Dim th As Thread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf work))
        th.Start()

    Next

    sw.Stop()


    MsgBox(sw.Elapsed.ToString())

End Sub

Private Sub work()
End Sub
```

If you press the button on the form, 150 threads are started in a loop. Their work sub doesn't actually do anything...it's just an exercise in starting a lot of threads.

I'm running this on a 16 core machine and it takes nearly half a second to complete. This is pretty outrageous considering that when this code is implemented in my app, it takes a shorter amount of time to run the work sub (when it actually contains useful routines) on a single thread than it does using all 16 cores.

Why is it taking so long to start the threads? As soon as you take out the "th.start()" line, the code executes in a half a millisecond.

Is there a faster way to start threads? Should I be using a threadpool system instead? Seems like multithreading is pointless when it can actually result in much slower speeds than single-threading....given that it can take so long to simply boot up all the threads.

Comment: What makes you think that adding threads will solve any problems for you? They often create more problems than they solve.

Comment: I'm processing many different pieces of geometry in my app at once. I figured multiple threads used to calculate things for each piece of independent geometry asynchronously is better than one thread cycling through each piece of geometry synchronously.

Comment: It's quite possible that calling `th.Start()` causes the current CPU to start running the thread you just started, making the loop take a lot longer than you expect. What happens if you have one loop to create the threads and another loop to start them all?

Answer (score 1):

Running 150 threads is almost always a bad idea. The scheduler will hate you and make your life miserable for contemplating such madness.

If you want really high-performance code, you should run about the same number of threads as there are cores, and do everything asynchronously (for I/O-heavy loads) or sequentially (for CPU-heavy loads) within each thread.

Running tasks through one of the standard thread pools is a pretty good compromise.

Comment: Well...here's my question about that: When I reduce the number of threads to the number of cores on my system, I don't get a performance boost. I get exact the same speed as I would expect, if the speed of each thread was determined by their performance in the 150-thread loop. (ie, reducing the iterations of the loop---and therefore the total number of threads---from 150 to 15 reduces the total calculation time from .5 seconds to .05 seconds. Still an average speed of .003 seconds/thread in both cases.

Comment: @Tyson: There is a substantial amount of overhead in spinning up a thread. You probably aren't giving each thread enough work to justify this overhead. In fact, your total workload of 0.5 ms is well below the typical time slice of 20–200 ms.